# Extract independent sub-systems from a bigger linear Eq. System

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, systems-of-equations

I'll start with an example:
imaging we have 6 variables, x1 to x6, and 4 equations:

1: `x1 + 2 * x2 = 4`

2: `-3 * x3 + x4 + x5 = -2`

3: `x3 - x5 = 4`

4: `x6 = 0`

as you can see there is no relation between say `x5` and `x2`, i mean if right hand side of equation #2 changes from `-2` to `2`, then `x3`, `x4` and `x5` will be affected, but `x1` and `x2` will not affect because no equation connects `x2` and `x5` together. I will call these, independent sub systems in next. So there is 3 independent sub systems in above system:

so subsystems are equations: {1}, {2, 3}, {4}

## Real Question

is how i can determine independent equations using standard matrix operations or algorithms?

## A probable solution (need to be proven!):

above system can fit on a `4 x 6` matrix each row a eq. and each column for a variable:

```
+1 +2 +0 +0 +0 +0
+0 +0 -3 +1 +1 +0
+0 +0 +1 -1 +0 +0
+0 +0 +0 +0 +0 +1
```

It's nonzero pattern (say matrix P) is:

```
1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1
```

if i do a transpose(P) * P, then nonzero pattern of result is:

```
1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1
```

It is like an square adjacency matrix that shows the relation of variables. `x1` and `x2` are adjacent, `x3`, `x4` and `x5` are adjacent and `x6` is alone! so doing a graph search starting from first unseen node can give me disconnected three sets of the matrix ({x1,x2}, {x3,x4,x5}, {x6}). and finally i'll extract equations having each of these sets with programming. I'm not sure if this way is true or accidentally works fine here! It was just a suggestion, any other suggestion is quite welcome.

-- edit:
I need this to be proven: multiplication of talked nonzero pattern and its transpose will give me the adjacency matrix of variables in the system. i think it can be sort of graph producing.

Comment: Your method shouldn't work in general, simply because the two matrices $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\ 2&1\end{pmatrix}$$ have the same non-zero pattern, but the first one has rank=1, while the second one is full rank. When you want to determine if some vectors are linearly independent, you do care about their actual entries, not only whether they are zero or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third matrix defines a graph in which the nodes are variables, and there's an edge between node $i$ and node $j$ exactly when there's an equation containing both $x_i$ and $x_j$.

What you're now looking for are the connected components of this graph. A typical method is breadth-first search, in which you take a list of all nodes, and associate to each a label (initially $0$; a node with label "0" we'll call "unlabeled"). You then grab the first unlabeled node (which is node $1$), label it "1", and then assign the label "1" also to any of its neighbors that are currently labelled "0", and continue recursively until all of that first node's neighbors, and their neighbors, and so on, have been marked "1". (In your example, this would give label "1" to nodes $1$ and $2$). Then you continue through the node-list, searching for the next unlabeled node. (In your example, node 3). You assign it label $2$, and recursively assign this label to all its children, their children, etc. (In your example, nodes $3$, $4$, and $5$ all get labelled "2"). Then you search for the NEXT unlabelled node, label it "3", and again recursively label its neighbors, their neighbors, etc. (In your example, nodes $6$ and $7$ get label $3$). You stop when there are no more unlabelled nodes.

This process takes time $O(E + V)$, where $V$ is the number of nodes ($6$ in your example), and $E$ the number of edges (which could be as large as $V*V$, but in your case, it's just $8$.)

**Post-comment addition**
Call the first matrix $A$.

Suppose that $x_i$ and $x_j$ appear in equation $k$. Then the $k$th row of $A$ will contain a $1$ in positions $i$ and $j$, i.e., $a_{ki} = a_{kj} = 1$. Note that the matrix $A$ has all nonnegative entries.

Now let's look at $B = A^t A$. We know that 
\begin{align}
b_{ij} 
&= \sum_q a^t_{iq}a_{qj} \\
&= \sum_q a_{qi}a_{qj} \\
&\ge  a_{ki}a_{kj} & \text{because all terms of the sum are nonneg}
&=  1.
\end{align}

Hence if $x_i$ and $x_j$ appear in the same equation, then the $ij$ entry of $B$ is nonzero (and so is the $ji$ entry, because $B$ is symmetric: $B^t = (A^t A)^t = A^t (A^t)^t = A^t A = B$).

Suppose now that for some $i$ and $j$, we have $b_{ij} > 0$. Then at least one of the terms in the sum for $b_{ij} = \sum_q a_{qi}a_{qj}$ must be positive. Suppose it's the $k$th one. Then $a_{ki}$ and $a_{kj}$ are both nonzero, and hence $x_i$ and $x_j$ are "related" by equation $k$.

I think that establishes what you need.

Comment: This was exactly what I meant, thanks... How can it be proved? is it a well known procedure or algorithm? does any one used this solution (multiplying nonzero pattern) before? does it have a name that i do not know yet?

Comment: I need this to be proven: multiplication of nonzero pattern and its transpose will give me the adjacency matrix of variable. i think it can be sort of graph producing.

Comment: See post-comment addition.